# Is it possible to configure an observable property as readonly using community toolkit?

Tags: mvvm, community-toolkit-mvvm

i am using CommunityToolkit to configure the binding properties in the view model, but in some cases I would like to set the property only as readonly. So I am tryiung this:

```
[ObservableProperty]
public MyType _myProperty{ get; private set; }
```

But this is only possible with fields, not with properties.

Is it possible to set a readonly property with CommunityToolkit?

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if `ObservableProperty` is the incorrect thing for you here then, since the general idea behind using that is that you get the property change notifications and all the other goodness wired up automatically. Can you explain a little more about how you're using this, and why you wouldn't want it to be set from your view?

Comment: Well, I would like that the property would be updated only from the view model, no from the view. In fact, in the view you can set the type of binding as two ways or only one direction, so what I would like to want it is to set the property in the view model as read only, to avoid the need to trust that the view will be setted in the correct way.

Comment: I’m on mobile so forgive the formatting but if you really _need_ to do this, theoretically you may be able to implement a partial OnMyPropertyChanging method and try to do something there to prevent the change. Maybe newValue = oldValue or some such. Not sure if that would work…

Comment: Yes, it is an option to implement PropertyChanging instead to wait until PropertyChanged. I will follow this way. Really it is a particular case.